# How can I import data from 1st table to a 2nd table on the same database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I can do this in SQL Server Management Studio, but when it comes to C#, I'm hopeless.

SQL Server Management Studio query:

```
INSERT INTO LoginDetails  
    SELECT Username, Password   
    FROM AccountLogin;
```

The following code saves data on a local db:

```
con.Open();
string query = "INSERT INTO AccountLogin (Name,LastName,TelNo,Email,Password,RepeatPassword,Username,TypeofRegistration,JobPosition) VALUES ('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtlastname.Text + "','" + txttelno.Text + "','" + txtemail.Text + "','" + txtaccpassword.Text + "','" + txtrepaccpassword.Text + "','" + txtaccusername.Text + "','" + TypeofREgistration.GetItemText(TypeofREgistration.SelectedItem) + "','" + JobPosition.GetItemText(JobPosition.SelectedItem) + "')";
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("REGISTRATION COMPLETE!");
```

Now i want to write a query that at the same time ,the data that i first save to a table of the local db to be saved in the 2nd table of the same local db

Comment: What's the problem when doing the very same thing from C#?

Comment: We're getting closer to the heart of the matter.  Learn to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Does your code produce an error?  Give us that information.

Comment: i want to write a query that at the same time ,the data that i first save to a table of the local db to be saved in the 2nd table of the same local db

Comment: Write another query that inserts that data into the LoginDetails table.  Use a Transaction to make sure both queries work.  And don't disregard the tip on using sql parameters.  Your query is dangerous.

Comment: You don't need a "transfer".  You need a second query and a [transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx) on both queries.

Answer (score 1):

If the databases are within the same SQL Serve instance, then you can do it like this. Also assuming you are using the default dbo schema.

```
INSERT INTO [Database1].[dbo].[LoginDetails]
SELECT Username, Password
FROM [Database2].[dbo].[AccountLogin]
```